# How Much Does a Petrified Character Weigh?

Tags: dnd-5e, conditions, weight

This came up in a session this weekend. One of my players was turned to stone (petrified) during combat. After combat, the rest of the party wanted to drag the statue around the rest of the dungeon, in hopes of finding a way to cure them. (And not wanting to leave the statue alone)

In lieu of any specific ruling on the matter, and because the half-orc has a STR of 19, we hand-waved the weight of the statue as irrelevant. But, if it weren't: **How much would a petrified character weigh as a statue?**

One of my players made the "how much does 150 pounds of feathers weigh" argument, but that didn't sit right with me, and I happened upon why only after the fact: because the density of stone is much higher (hopefully) than that of flesh. Therefore, the mass would scale at an equal ratio, assuming the same volume (that's d=m/v) -- but I don't know the density ratio of stone vs flesh. Can someone provide that, or at least an educated guess?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

### A petrified character weighs 10 times their normal weight

This is answered in the first bullet point of the [petrified condition](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions#Petrified) (emphasis added):

> - A petrified creature is transformed, along with any nonmagical object it is wearing or carrying, into a solid inanimate substance (usually stone). **Its weight increases by a factor of ten**, and it ceases aging.

If the creature is turned into an unusual substance with a density very different from that of solid mundane stone, the DM could modify this weight factor to make it larger or smaller, as needed. But for your ordinary everyday turning to stone, the answer is 10x normal weight. Note that "normal weight" would mean the weight of *everything* that was petrified. This includes the weight of any of their clothing and equipment that was turned to stone along with them.

Comment: Jesus christ thats massive! In real life the actual increase would roughly 3x.

Comment: @BrunoSouza I suspect at least part of the reason is to make it easy to compute the new weight: just add a zero to the end, and then erase it when the character is restored.

Comment: Thanks for finding this, Ryan! I'm ashamed to say I didn't even check the appendix, I have the DM screen from the Starter Set and read the petrification condition on there, and it didn't say anything about the weight increase. I'll leave this question open, but I'm 99% sure you've got the checkmark for this one. Thanks again!

Comment: @BrunoSouza Wouldn't that depend on the stone? Granite != Pumice.

Comment: @Slagmoth yes, i used granite as the base there as it's a very common type of stone.

Comment: @3d12: don't be afraid to accept an obviously-correct answer; it doesn't close the question.  Someone else can still post another answer that's better or if the accepted answer turns out to be flawed.  Especially for a question that turned out to have a simple answer, people can read it if they're curious what the answer is, but it's not like you need to encourage anyone else to post another answer that explains it differently.